# Item does not show in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

This is my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        _items.Add(mojTelefon.Naziv);
        _items.Add(mojTelefon.Specifikacije);
        _items.Add(mojTelefon.Proizvodjac);
        _items.Add(mojTelefon.Opis);
        _items2.Add(mojTelefon.Kolicina);



        listBox1.DataSource = _items2;
        listBox1.DataSource = _items;



    }
```

items2 is a int value, when i press button on the form , he shows items but not items2 ... Can someone plz help

Comment: listbox datasource cannot have multiple lists. You need to add all your values to one list and assign that list as a datasource.

Comment: Because you are overwritting the datasource. The last code works. So the datasource is items.

Comment: You need to assign _items2 to listBox2. You are overriding listBox1.DataSource with _items

Comment: Of course `listBox1` shows `_items` instead of `_items2` - you told it to. Right there, in your code. See that line that says `listBox1.DataSource = _items;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListBox` doesn't allow setting multiple `DataSources`

I would suggest merge both the lists and set as `DataSource`

```
_items.AddRange(_items2) 
listBox1.DataSource = _items;
```

or, if you need `_items & _items2` for later reference, you could create new `List` as shown below and use it.

```
List<string>  list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(_items2)
list.AddRange(_items);
listBox1.DataSource = list;
```

Alternatively (as @Vincent mentioned) you could also use `Linq` extensions to create new `List` as below.

```
listBox1.DataSource = _items.Concat(_items2).ToList();
```

Comment: You could also just go `listBox1.DataSource = _items.Concat(_items2).ToList()`

Comment: Intentionally dropped that Idea thinking it may be advance to OP, but seems it is good idea to mention this as well. I'll update it.